# Write a kotlin program that prints the number that is repeated the most in a consecutive way

Tags: kotlin

I'm kind of stuck, I don't know how to make the second loop to start 1 position above the first loop in Kotlin.

I have an array (named myArray) with 10 elements, I need to Write a Kotlin program that prints the number that has the most consecutive repeated number in the array and also prints the number of times it appears in the sequence.
The program must parse the array from left to right so that if two numbers meet the condition, the one that appears first from left to right will be printed.

Longest: 3
Number: 8

```
fun main() {
    val myArray: IntArray = intArrayOf(1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,8,8)    
    
    for((index , value) in myArray.withIndex()){   
        
        var inx = index + 1
        var count = 0
        var longest = 0
        var number = 0
        
        for((inx,element) in myArray.withIndex()) {
            
            if(value == element ){
                count+=
            }
        }   
        if(longest < count){
            longest = count
            number = value
        }    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm against just dropping answers, but it is quite late for me, so I'll leave this answer here and edit it tomorrow with more info on how each part works. I hope that maybe in the meanwhile it will help you to gain some idea to where you might be going wrong.

```
val results = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()

(0..myArray.size - 2).forEach { index ->
    val current = myArray[index]
    if (current == myArray[index + 1]) {
        results[current] = (results[current] ?: 1) + 1
    }
}

val (max, occurrences) = results.maxByOrNull { it.value } ?: run { println("No multiple occurrences"); return }

println("Most common consecutive number $max, with $occurrences occurrences")
```

Alternatively if the `intArray` would be a list, or if we allowed to change it to a list `myArray.toList()`, you could replace the whole `forEach` loop with a [zipWithNext](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html). But I'm pretty sure that this is a HW question, so I doubt this is the expected way of solving it.

```
myList.zipWithNext { a, b ->
    if (a == b) results[a] = (results[a] ?: 1) + 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!, I understood each line, except  what is and why you use kotlin before the run and kotlin.io.

Comment: oh, the `run` and `println` have `kotlin.` in front because I tested that code in a multi-language file, I forgot to remove them, you shouldn't need to add `kotlin.` to them, I'll edit the answer and remove them. The `run {}` creates a function block. It is a [scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#run) that basically allows us to create a piece of code there. Normally you could just replace `run { println("etc"); return }` with a simple `return`, but I thought it would be a nice idea to also print something, so that one knows why the code finished. 1/2

Comment: So you could have there `results.maxByOrNull { it.value } ?: return` instead of the whole `run { //etc`.